# How to save state of checkboxes in database (both true and false states)

Tags: android, checkbox

In my Android app I have a DB where store `Phrase` objects, and `Theme` objects, among other data. These phrases have an attribute `sourceLanguage` (String) and an `isSelected` attribute (String too, since SQLITE doesn't have boolean - can't recall why I didn't use 0 and 1, but that's not relevant). The themes contain one or more phrases.

I have one activity where the user is given a `listView` with a list of themes. When he picks a theme, an alert dialog displays with a `checkbox` list of phrases so he can select one or more. I'd like to update each phrase in the DB using the information from the AlertDialog checkboxes, changing `isSelected` to "true" or to "false", depending on the user's choice.

My difficulty is that the examples I found online so far allow to save the "true" state of the elements, but not the "false". So if a phrase is stored as "true", and then changed to "false", it will simply not appear in the `selectedItems`, and I don't have a reference to access it and modify it to "false". I've come up with a couple of solutions, but I'm not confident about any, and this is where you could help me.

My AlertDialog method:

```
private void showAlertDialog(int themeId, String themeName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

// Build the list of phrases for respective theme and list of previously selected items
final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
List<Phrase> allThemePhr = db.getPhrases("with_theme", themeId, null); // all phrases for selected theme 
CharSequence[] sourceLanguageAllPhr = new String[allThemePhr.size()]; // source language of all phrases for selected theme
boolean[] selectedItems = new boolean[allThemePhr.size()]; // selected items only
final List<String> sourceLanguageSelectedPhr = new ArrayList<String>();
final List<String> sourceLanguageNOTSelectedPhr = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0 ; i < allThemePhr.size() ; i++){
    sourceLanguageAllPhr[i] = allThemePhr.get(i).getSource_language();
    selectedItems[i] = false;
    if (allThemePhr.get(i).getItemSelected() == "true"){
        selectedItems[i] = true;
        sourceLanguageSelectedPhr.add(allThemePhr.get(i).getSource_language());
    }
}


// Build the dialog
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
final ArrayList selectedPhrases = new ArrayList();

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PickTheme.this);
builder.setTitle(themeName)
        .setMultiChoiceItems(sourceLanguageAllPhr, selectedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(isChecked){
                    selectedPhrases.add(which);
                    //sourceLanguageSelectedPhr.add(selectedPhrases.get(which).toString());
                } else if (selectedPhrases.contains(which)){
                    selectedPhrases.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                    //sourceLanguageSelectedPhr.remove(selectedPhrases.get(which).toString());
                    //sourceLanguageNOTSelectedPhr.add(selectedPhrases.get(which).toString());
                }
            }
        })
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //for (String sourceLanguage : sourceLanguageSelectedPhr){
                    //db.updatePhrase(sourceLanguage, "true");
                    //Log.i("selectedPhrase", selectedPhrases.get(which).toString());
                //}
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

In my DatabaseHelper class, I've defined these methods that can be used to update phrases:

```
// updating a phrase

public int updatePhrase(Phrase phrase){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COLUMN_PHRASE_ID, phrase.getWord_id());
values.put(COLUMN_SOURCE_LANGUAGE, phrase.getSource_language());
values.put(COLUMN_TARGET_LANGUAGE, phrase.getTarget_language());
values.put(COLUMN_PHRASE_REMINDER_DATE, phrase.getTarget_language());
values.put(COLUMN_PHRASE_THEME_ID, phrase.getTheme_id());
values.put(COLUMN_PHRASE_REMINDER_ID, phrase.getTheme_id());

int phraseUpdated = db.update(PHRASES_TABLE, values, COLUMN_PHRASE_ID + " =?", new String[] {String.valueOf(phrase.getWord_id())});
db.close();
return phraseUpdated;
}

// updating a phrase based on given source_language
public void updatePhrase(String sourceLanguage, String isSelected){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String updateStatement = "UPDATE " + PHRASES_TABLE
                             + " SET " + COLUMN_ITEM_SELECTED + " = " + isSelected
                             + " WHERE " + COLUMN_SOURCE_LANGUAGE + " = " + sourceLanguage;
    db.execSQL(updateStatement);
}
```

So far, I've thought of a few solutions, this one seemed the best: when a phrase is selected / de-selected, get it from the `allThemePhr`, update the object accordingly, and save it in another List. If user clicks OK, use that list to update the DB. My problem is: how to I match the value of `which` with the respective object in `allThemePhr` ? If I can figure out how to get the checkbox text, that should be acceptable, since it corresponds to the `source_language` attribute of `phrase`?

Maybe there is a simpler solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a match between the index which and the index the phrase objects have in the global phrases List `allThemePhr`, so no need to go through the string of the checkbox / the value of `sourceLanguage`.

So, I simply created a map where I store the correspondence between the index `which` and the status of the checkbox (`isChecked`). Then, if the user presses "OK", I iterate through that map, get the corresponding phrase object from `allThemePhr` and update it.

Here is the final code:

```
private void showAlertDialog(int themeId, String themeName) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

// Build the list of phrases for respective theme and list of previously selected items
final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
final List<Phrase> allThemePhr = db.getPhrases("with_theme", themeId, null); // all phrases for selected theme 
final Map<Integer, Boolean> selectionChanges = new HashMap<Integer,Boolean>();
CharSequence[] sourceLanguageAllPhr = new String[allThemePhr.size()]; // source language of all phrases for selected theme
boolean[] selectedItems = new boolean[allThemePhr.size()]; // selected items only


for (int i = 0 ; i < allThemePhr.size() ; i++){
    Phrase phrase = allThemePhr.get(i);
    sourceLanguageAllPhr[i] = phrase.getSource_language();


    if (phrase.getItemSelected().equals("true")){
        selectedItems[i] = true;
    }
}


// Build the dialog
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PickTheme.this);
builder.setTitle(themeName)
        .setMultiChoiceItems(sourceLanguageAllPhr, selectedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                    boolean isChecked) {

                selectionChanges.put(which, isChecked);


            }
        })
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (Map.Entry<Integer, Boolean> entry : selectionChanges.entrySet()){
                    Phrase phrase = allThemePhr.get(entry.getKey());

                    phrase.setItemSelected(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));


                }
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
}
```