# Using a SQlite database to store checkbox states in custom baseadapter listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, checkbox, android-listview

I am using a custom BaseAdapter listview to display a list of installed apps with a checkbox next to it. I am trying to save the each listview item and checkbox state in an SQLite database after attempting to do so with SharedPreferences.

I would like it to store the state of the checkbox once the listview has been closed and once the application has been closed aswell.

[image]

I have done much research and have been at this for well over a week, but haven't been able to produce or find a solution that works for me.

[How to save state of checkboxes in database (both true and false states)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144447/how-to-save-state-of-checkboxes-in-database-both-true-and-false-states)

[Storing the state of checkbox in listview while using custom BaseAdapter in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610267/storing-the-state-of-checkbox-in-listview-while-using-custom-baseadapter-in-andr)

Here is my BaseAdapter class:

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.R;

import java.util.List;

public class ApkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



    //Pastebin link:  http://pastebin.com/LGRicg4U , http://pastebin.com/c4WfmhMK http://pastebin.com/gFuuM4dY

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    List<PackageInfo> packageList;
    Activity context;
    PackageManager packageManager;
    boolean[] itemChecked;

    String PACKAGE_NAME;


    public ApkAdapter(Activity context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
                      PackageManager packageManager) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.packageList = packageList;
        this.packageManager = packageManager;
        itemChecked = new boolean[packageList.size()];


    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView apkName;
        CheckBox ck1;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return packageList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return packageList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.appname);
            holder.ck1 = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            //holder.ck1.setTag(packageList.get(position));

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        // ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);


        Drawable appIcon = packageManager
                .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);

        PACKAGE_NAME = packageInfo.packageName;

        final String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
                packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
        appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 80, 80);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
        holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
        holder.apkName.setText(appName);

        holder.ck1.setChecked(false);


        if (itemChecked[position])
            holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

        Log.d("just loaded??", appName);


        Log.d("just loaded 2?", appName);


        holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               /* sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("apps", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                holder.ck1.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean(appName,false));
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(appName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();*/

                if (holder.ck1.isChecked()) {
                    itemChecked[position] = true;
                    holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
                    Log.i("This is", " checked: " + position);
                    //editor.putBoolean(appName, true);
                    Log.d("put true", appName);

                    //editor.apply();

                } else {
                    itemChecked[position] = false;
                    holder.ck1.setChecked(false);
                    Log.i("This is", " not checked: " + position);
                    //editor.putBoolean(appName, false);
                    Log.d("put false", appName);

                    //editor.apply();

                }

            }

        });


        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Here is my DataBaseHandler class:

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

/**
 * Created by Spicycurryman on 8/5/14.
 */
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "packagenameManager";

    // Packagename table name
    private static final String TABLE_PACKAGE_NAME = "packagenames";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_PACKAGE_NAME = "packagenames";
    private static final String KEY_STATE = "state";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PACKAGE_NAME + "("
                + KEY_PACKAGE_NAME + " STRING PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_STATE + " INT,"
                 + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PACKAGE_NAME);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new packagename
    void addPackageName(PackageName packageName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_STATE, packageName.getPACKAGENAME()); // Packagename

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_PACKAGE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single package
    PackageName getPackageName(String packagename) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PACKAGE_NAME, new String[] {KEY_PACKAGE_NAME,
                        KEY_STATE }, KEY_PACKAGE_NAME + "=?",
                new String[] { packagename }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        PackageName packageName = new PackageName((cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getInt(1));
        // return packagename
        return packageName;
    }

    // Getting All packagenames
    public List<PackageName> getAllPackageNames() {
        List<PackageName> packageNameList = new ArrayList<PackageName>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PACKAGE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                PackageName packageName = new PackageName();
                packageName.setPACKAGENAME(cursor.getString(0));
                packageName.setState(cursor.getInt(1));
                // Adding contact to list
                packageNameList.add(packageName);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return packagename list
        return packageNameList;
    }

    // Updating single packagename
    public int updatePackageName(PackageName packageName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_STATE, packageName.getState());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_PACKAGE_NAME, values, KEY_PACKAGE_NAME + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(packageName.getPACKAGENAME()) });
    }

    // Deleting single packagename
    public void deletePackageName(PackageName packageName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_PACKAGE_NAME, KEY_PACKAGE_NAME + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(packageName.getPACKAGENAME()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting packagename Count
    public int getPackageNameCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PACKAGE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

And lastly here is my Object class:

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

/**
 * Created by Spicycurryman on 8/5/14.
 */
public class PackageName {

    //private variables
    String _packagename;
    int _state;

    // Empty constructor
    public PackageName(){

    }
    // constructor
    public PackageName(String packagename, int state){
        this._packagename = packagename;
        this._state = state;
    }

    // constructor
    public PackageName(int state){
        this._state = state;
    }
    // getting PACKAGENAME
    public String getPACKAGENAME(){
        return this._packagename;
    }

    // setting packagename
    public void setPACKAGENAME(String packagename){
        this._packagename = packagename;
    }

    // getting state
    public int getState(){
        return this._state;
    }

    // setting state
    public void setState(int state){
        this._state = state;
    }


}
```

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

ListView_CheckBoxActivity class

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class ListView_CheckBoxActivity extends Activity {
CheckboxAdapter listItemAdapter;
DataHandler handler;
Button cancel;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    handler=new DataHandler(getBaseContext());
    handler.open();
    System.out.println("Entered in the checked box");
    Button getValue=(Button)findViewById(R.id.get_value);
    cancel=(Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    getValue.setOnClickListener(listener);  
    //listview 
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);        
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listData=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    int size=0;
    Cursor getSize=handler.CategoryNameLength();
    getSize.moveToFirst();
    size=getSize.getInt(0);

    String[] name=new String[size];
    int catgoryIndex=0;
    Cursor getCategoryName=handler.CategoryName();

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    if(getCategoryName.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            name[catgoryIndex]=getCategoryName.getString(0);
            System.out.println("Strng"+name[catgoryIndex]);
            catgoryIndex++;

        }while(getCategoryName.moveToNext());
    }
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){            
        HashMap<String, Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        System.out.println("Line1");
        map.put("friend_image", R.drawable.icon);
        map.put("friend_username", name[i]);
        listData.add(map);
    }       
    listItemAdapter = new CheckboxAdapter(this, listData);
    list.setAdapter(listItemAdapter);
}

OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        HashMap<Integer, Boolean> state =listItemAdapter.state;         
        String options="***Selected***";        
        for(int j=0;j<listItemAdapter.getCount();j++){
            System.out.println("state.get("+j+")=="+state.get(j));
               //checking the state is on , if on i,m updating my table
            if(state.get(j)!=null){
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, Object> map=(HashMap<String, Object>) listItemAdapter.getItem(j);
                String username=map.get("friend_username").toString();
                Cursor getID=handler.getIdForCategory(username);
                getID.moveToFirst();
                int id=getID.getInt(0);
                System.out.println("ID=="+id);
                handler.updateDefaulttable_flag_1(id);//updating my table
                options+="\n"+username;

            }
           //same as checking sate is off, if off updating my database table
            if(state.get(j)== null){
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, Object> map=(HashMap<String, Object>) listItemAdapter.getItem(j);
                String username=map.get("friend_username").toString();
                Cursor getID=handler.getIdForCategory(username);
                getID.moveToFirst();
                int id=getID.getInt(0);
                System.out.println("ID=="+id);
                handler.updateDefaulttable_flag_0(id);
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), options, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
};  
}
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:paddingBottom="4dip" 
 android:paddingRight="12dip" >
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/friend_image"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:paddingTop="6dip"
 android:paddingLeft="2dip"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" /> 
 <TextView android:id="@+id/friend_username"  
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:textSize="18dip" 
 android:textColor="#ccc"     
 android:paddingTop="6dip"
 android:paddingRight="2dip"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/friend_image"    />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/friend_id"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
 android:layout_below="@+id/friend_username"        
 android:layout_marginRight="36dip"
 android:paddingRight="2dip"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/friend_image"    
 android:textColor="#fff"                        
 android:maxLines="2" />
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/selected" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="36dip"        
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:focusable="false"  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

CheckboxAdapter class

```
public class CheckboxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
DataHandler handler;
SQLiteDatabase db;

Context context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listData;    
HashMap<Integer, Boolean> state = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();      

public CheckboxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listData = listData;   
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friend_image);
    image.setBackgroundResource((Integer) listData.get(position).get("friend_image"));
    TextView username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friend_username);
    username.setText((String) listData.get(position).get("friend_username"));
    CheckBox check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.selected);    
    boolean isChecked=true;
    handler=new DataHandler(context);
    handler.open();

    Cursor setUserFlag = handler.setCheckFlagID();
    if(setUserFlag.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            int getid = setUserFlag.getInt(0);
            getid = getid - 1;
            state.put(getid , isChecked);   
        }while(setUserFlag.moveToNext());
    }
    check.setChecked((state.get(position) == null ? false : true));

    handler.close();


    check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                state.put(position, isChecked);                 
            } else {
                state.remove(position);             
            }
        }
    });

    check.setChecked((state.get(position) == null ? false : true));
    return convertView;
}
}
```

datahandler

```
public Cursor setCheckFlagID() {
        return db.rawQuery("select _id from default_category_table where flag=1;", null);

    }
public void updateDefaulttable_flag_1(int id) {
        String selectQuery = "UPDATE  default_category_table SET flag=1 WHERE _id='"+id+"'";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        System.out.print("Count"+cursor.getCount()); 

    }

    public void updateDefaulttable_flag_0(int id) {
        String selectQuery = "UPDATE  default_category_table SET flag=0 WHERE _id='"+id+"'";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        System.out.print("Count"+cursor.getCount());
    }
public Cursor getIdForCategory(String username) {
        return db.rawQuery("select _id from default_category_table where   category='"+username+"';", null);
    }
public Cursor CategoryNameLength() {
        return db.rawQuery("select count(category) from Default_Category_Table", null);

    }
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="272dp"
    android:layout_weight="5.16" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/get_value"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I apologize, but I am kind of overwhelmed by your answer. Is it possible to get an explanation?

Comment: while developing my project i'm having the same task of storing the check and unchecked item to the database. Initially i downloaded the sample program from net, but it shows the selected items in Toast of what i been checked in the list. So with that example model i extended to save the marked and unmarked to the database which was in boolean type . I'm not sure how much i know this code fully . But tell me which part i wanna explain, i'll do my best

Comment: In short main xml-shows the list view and two button (cancel and save),item xml defines what have to be in each listview(so their comes check box), when my activity starts with the help of array list and hash map i'm stuffing my data to the adapter, there size var. defines how many item i wanna add, that many times my for runs.Check the cancel Onclick listener there comes how to store the marked and unmarked to the database. One imp. thing when the activity open for the next time what ever u marked has to be remains    marked,for that in my adapter class check view getview() method

Comment: Okay I see thx. I am trying to figure out what to do with ListView_CheckBoxActivity and also what modifications I have to make to my DatabaseHandler class. Am I doing something wrong with my object and database class?

Comment: Till now what are the things working in your code..? so that i can get an idea of explaining.

Comment: I really am confused as of what to do with ListView_CheckBoxActivity... but my adapter and xml files are fine

Comment: First try this, Getting all the app image and appname from your database(some resource) put all the value in to hash map(change the loop to ur structure),then add it to array list finally set it to adapter 'listItemAdapter = new CheckboxAdapter(this, listData);
     list.setAdapter(listItemAdapter);' and check it works . This is the part i'm doing in oncreate() of my ListView_CheckBoxActivity

Comment: Okay I think I might understand. so this would all be done in my adapter class?

Comment: All the code i'm talking about is in Oncreate() of ListView_CheckBoxActivity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59220/discussion-between-xijiaopin-and-saravanaraja-t).

Comment: finally found out the [link](http://blog.csdn.net/qu213/article/details/9289349) for u, this example was my start when i'm doing this same task, here in this example they use default string values and id to post it to the list view with out database . So this was the code i been used and altered it & save in database, check the changes im my code and ter and use it your way.